# Eventos silenciosos del binlog MySQL en - Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, procesos-en-segundo-plano, log

**Reeditado domingo 14 de febrero de 2021**

Realicé un *script* que básicamente debe retransmitir eventos a un servidor.

Se crearon *subprocesos* para aligerar la carga del padre y uno de ellos es el que escucha los eventos específicos que se generan en la *DB* de MySQL. Si encuentra alguno, lo reporta al padre. Éste a su vez crea nuevos *subprocesos* para procesarlos de forma independiente por cada uno de ellos.

Para esto usé *SONGJI*, pero la consola se colma de *logs*, al punto, que apenas si se puede notar algún reporte enviado por los *subprocesos* al culminar su tarea.

Entonces, decidí silenciar el *subproceso*, pero esto terminaba por matarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En fin, luego di con la solución cuya respuesta comparto.

Answer (score 0):

Para corregir esto cambié a una dependencia diferente **@rodrigogs/mysql-events**.

Esta es una variante de *ZONJGI* y pueden revisar la documentación de esta librería [aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rodrigogs/mysql-events).

Este último resolvió el problema de impresión de *logs* que eran muy molestos y ocupaban toda la consola.

Aquí un extracto de código cuando retorna al padre los eventos que captura como objeto.

**Fragmento de código:**

```js
data = {
  a: num++,
  b: ldb,
  c: xx,
  d: xx.alarm ? xx.alarm : "",
  e: ldb.deviceid,
};

return process.send(data);
```

Como ya lo dije antes, los subprocesos realizan el envío e imprimen un reporte en la consola.

Para crear múltiples procesos que realicen la tarea se realizó la siguiente lógica con la ayuda de `eval`.

**Fragmento de código:**

```js
eval ('var pls' + a.a  + '= fork.fork(path.join(__dirname, "/modulos/chi/rsm"), {silent: false})')
eval ('pls' + a.a + '.on("message", (p) => { pls' + a.a + '.kill() })')
eval ('pls' + a.a + '.send({ a: a.b, b: a.c, c: q })')
```

'var pls' + **a.a** esta es una variable que puede ir en un `for` o `while`. En mi caso, lo encadené a los eventos que me envía `mysql_events`.

Al final, la consola quedó mucho más elegante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]